# Collection View Cells alpha is changing after scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I created a Collection View where the cells have a view inside. The views have a alpha value of 0.65. When I scroll, the view gets brighter. Maybe the views will be stacked on top of each other?

MY CODE:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LevelStufenCell

    cell.levelViewBack = UIView()
    cell.levelViewBack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.height, height: cell.frame.width)
    cell.levelViewBack.layer.cornerRadius = cell.levelViewBack.frame.height * (36 / 198)
    cell.levelViewBack.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cell.levelViewBack.alpha = 0.65
    cell.insertSubview(cell.levelViewBack, at: 10)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not adding the subview in interface builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are ***reused***, so you are adding another `levelViewBack` to each cell every time the cells scroll into view.

You have defined `levelViewBack` inside your `LevelStufenCell` ... is it an `IBOutlet`? If so, you do not need to create a new one each time - simply remove this line:

```
cell.levelViewBack = UIView()
```

If it is *not* an `IBOutlet`, are you creating it inside `LevelStufenCell`? If so, again, simply remove that line. If not, check if it's been created before "creating it again":

```
if cell.levelViewBack == nil {
    cell.levelViewBack = UIView()
}
```